# Listen to a click event inside bindpopup with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, popup, event-listener, angular2

I'm using **Leaflet**, I have bound popups to layers, and created a `popupopen` event `listener` on the map as follow:

```
map.on('popupopen', this._managePopUp.bind(this));


_managePopUp(layer) {
        console.log('popup listened !');
        console.log(this.elRef);
        this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#Layer-delete').addEventListener('click', e => {
            this._removeLayerByBounds(layer);
        });
        this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#Layer-edit').addEventListener('click', e => {
            this._editLayerByBounds(layer);
        });
    }
```

The problem is that when the `#Layer-delete` and `#Layer-edit` click event `listeners` are not executed when a popup is called, so I need to re-click on the map then on the layer, then on the delete or edit button, so that it works.

I think the problem is that the `this.elRef` reference is not updated while clicking directly on layers.